# Renaming Corvid and WixCode to Velo after company rebrand?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

We recently [rebranded Wix's JavaScript Development Platform](https://cloud7.news/hosting/wix-rebrands-corvid-as-velo/) from Corvid (sound a little like a global pandemic?) to Velo for stated-pandemic reasons.

We also have an older name for this product from our initial launch, which is Wix Code. I am taking over the Stack Overflow management for our team, and I am trying to clean up our tagging system. I don't have enough reputation to suggest synonyms or retag for Velo, and we would need to have 25 or so questions asked to get enough points for synonym to be approved.

I am in need of some help with getting [wixcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wixcode) and [corvid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/corvid) to be synonyms of the new [velo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/velo) tag.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Asking a question here is the best way to accomplish this. Just wait for a mod to come along and they'll probably rename the tag for you (or ask additional questions if there are any, but it seems clear to me).

Comment: No clean-up is needed in those "older" tags by looking at the first 50 questions so I see no obstacles to get those synonyms in place.

Comment: (*"[Corvidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corvidae) is a cosmopolitan family of oscine passerine birds that contains the crows, ravens, rooks, jackdaws, jays, magpies, treepies, choughs, and nutcrackers. In common English, they are known as the crow family, or, more technically*, ***corvids***. ... ***Corvids*** *display remarkable intelligence for animals of their size and are among the most intelligent birds thus far studied."*)